# Array: how to achieved this kind of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

Good day, I'm doing a cart order service **API** for my study. and I was struggling with how to do multiple items check out.

First problem

> I don't know how to pass an array(*Like the output below*) from post request to my controller or method. After the user is done selecting his/her item(s).

Second

> How can I achieve an array(*Like the output below*)

When user 1234 selects 1 item the output will look like this.

```
Array ( [user_id] => 1234 
        [0] => Array ( 
                        [product_id]    => 123 
                        [product_name]  => sample product 1 
                        [product_desc]  => A sample product 
                        [product_price] => 100 
                    ) 
        )
```

When user 1234 selects 2 items. this will be the output.

```
Array ( [user_id] => 1234 
        [0] => Array ( 
                        [product_id]    => 1 
                        [product_name]  => sample product 1 
                        [product_desc]  => A sample product 
                        [product_price] => 100 
                    ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                        [product_id]    => 2 
                        [product_name]  => sample product 2 
                        [product_desc]  => A sample product 
                        [product_price] => 100 
                    ) 
        )
```

When user 12 selects 2 items. this will be the output.

```
Array ( [user_id] => 12 
        [0] => Array ( 
                        [product_id]    => 1
                        [product_name]  => sample product 2 
                        [product_desc]  => A sample product 
                        [product_price] => 100 
                    ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                        [product_id]    => 2 
                        [product_name]  => sample product 2 
                        [product_desc]  => A sample product 
                        [product_price] => 200 
                    ) 
        )
```

and soon...

**Edited** this is my test checkout form. For now it can only checkout single item at a time.

```
<form action="/test/api/checkoutItem" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_items_id" id="cart_items_id" value="55">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="11647748">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="70">
    <input type="input"  name="qty" id="qty">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkoutItem(Request $request)
{ 
    $id     = $request->user_id;
    //Status TESTED AND OK.
    try{
        //Check if cart has an item whith status id 1 (Added).
        $cart = \DB::table('cart_items')
                ->whereRaw('cart_items.id = ' .$request->cart_items_id. 
                    ' AND cart_items.product_id = ' .$request->product_id. 
                    ' AND cart_items.status_id = 1')->count();

        if($cart != NULL){

            Stripe::setApiKey( config('services.stripe.secret') );
            $student= \App\User::find($id);

            //Get the product details using the product_id
            $product= \App\Product::find($request->product_id);

            //Check if student's has no stripe id.
            if($student->stripe_id == NULL){
                //create stripe id for student.
                $customer= Customer::create([
                                            'email'    => request('stripeEmail'),
                                            'source'   => request('stripeToken')
                                            ]);
                //Update stripe_id from null to newly created stripe_id generated by stripe.
                $user= \App\User::where('id', $id)
                ->update( array('stripe_id' => $customer->id) ); 

                //Charge the student.
                Charge::create([
                    'customer'      => $customer->id,
                    'description'   => $product->description,
                    'amount'        => ($product->price * 100) * $request->qty, //Should be in cent.
                    'currency'      => 'aud',
                    'receipt_email' => $request->stripeEmail,
                    'metadata'      => array(
                                            "product_id"        => $request->product_id, 
                                            "product_name"      => $product->name,
                                            "product qty"       => $request->qty,
                                            "product_type_id"   => $product->product_type_id,
                                            "sub_type_id"       => $product->service_sub_type_id,
                                            "user_id"           => $id,
                                            "fullname"          => $student->first_name." ".$student->last_name,
                                            "email"             => $request->stripeEmail
                                            )
                    ]);
            //If student's has already stripe id, create a charge.   
            }else{
                //Charge
                Charge::create([
                    'customer'      => $student->stripe_id,
                    'description'   => $product->description,
                    'amount'        => ($product->price * 100) * $request->qty, //Should be in cent.
                    'currency'      => 'aud',
                    'receipt_email' => $student->email,
                    'metadata'      => array(
                                            "product_id"        => $request->product_id, 
                                            "product_name"      => $product->name,
                                            "product qty"       => $request->qty,
                                            "product_type_id"   => $product->product_type_id,
                                            "sub_type_id"       => $product->service_sub_type_id,
                                            "user_id"           => $id,
                                            "fullname"          => $student->first_name." ".$student->last_name,
                                            "email"             => $student->email
                                            )
                    ]); 
            }

            //If successfully charge, status_id wll be updated from 1(Added) to 2(Checkout).
            $upd_cart_items= \DB::table('cart_items')
            ->leftjoin('carts', 'cart_items.cart_id', '=', 'carts.id')
            ->whereRaw('cart_items.id = ' .$request->cart_items_id)
            ->update(['cart_items.quantity' => $request->qty,'cart_items.status_id' => 2, 
                      'cart_items.updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()]);

            return ['success' => true, 'message' => "Product was successfully purchased"];

        }
    }catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e){
        return['error' => $e];
    }
}
```

sorry for asking this foolish question.

But someone said:

> He who asks a question is a fool for five minutes; he who does not ask a question remains a fool forever

Comment: Sure, but it's impossible for us to answer your question with the information provided. I mean, we could tell you that `$array = array(array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'product'), array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'product2'));` will give you what you want. But that's probably not helpfull at all right? We don't know your setup. We don't know how you're handling the data. You're not showing us anything. All you do is asking us how to create a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @DavidJorHpan I already updated my question.

Comment: @icecub I already updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

> One feature of PHP's processing of POST and GET variables is that it
>   automatically decodes indexed form variable names.

You could do this

```
<form ....>
<input name="person[userId]" value="1234" />
<input name="person[0][product_id]" value="1" />
<input name="person[0][product_name]" value="sample product 1" />
...
<input name="person[1][product_id]" value="2" />
<input name="person[1][product_name]" value="sample product 2" />
</form>
```

In php you retrieve it by:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['person']);
//will get you something like:
    [user_id] => 1234
    [0] => Array ( 
              [product_id]    => 1
              [product_name]  => sample product 1 
          ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
              [product_id]    => 2 
              [product_name]  => sample product 2 
          ) 
?>
```